# How to publish single publications using artifactoryPublish

Tags: gradle, artifactory

I'm using 'artifactory-publish' and 'maven-publish' plugins for publishing to artifactory. Here is my code :

```
apply plugin: 'artifactory-publish'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
artifactory {
    contextUrl = "${artifactory_contextUrl}"
    publish {
        repository {
            repoKey = "${artifactory_repoKey}"
            username = "${artifactory_user}"
            password = "${artifactory_password}"
        }
    }
}
publishing {
   publications {
        publishPlugin(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
        }

        integTest(MavenPublication) {
            setArtifactId(project.name + '-' + integTestJar.appendix)
            artifact integTestJar.archivePath

        }
    }
}
artifactoryPublish {
    publications ('publishPlugin', 'integTest')
}
```

When I run artifactoryPublish, it publishes all the publications (i.e., publishPlugin, integTest). Is there a way where I can publish individual publication using artifactPublish ?

I know that 'gradle publishIntegTest' can be used to publish individual publication, but that requires me to define the repositories{} configuration inside the publishing{} block, which would be duplicating of the repository configuration. I'm looking for solution without doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can define any number of tasks of the type `BuildInfoPublicationsTask` and reconfigure them to publish another publication(s).

Comment: Where can I find the javadoc/example for BuildInfoPublicationsTask ?

Comment: It's not documented much, since it's not intended to be reconfigured directly. Your best hit will be [the source](https://github.com/JFrogDev/build-info/blob/master/build-info-extractor-gradle/src/main/groovy/org/jfrog/gradle/plugin/artifactory/task/BuildInfoPublicationsTask.java)